# Apply condition on a series

Tags: kql

What is the best way to apply condition on each element in a series, and store the result on a new [0, 1]^n series?

For example:

Apply condition : >= 10  on series : [4, 10, 100, 5]

will return:
[0, 1, 1, 0]

Comment: No theoretical questions on SO. You get what you ask for :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
let series = dynamic([4, 10, 100, 5]);
let 10ths = repeat(10, array_length(series));
print array_iff(series_greater_equals(series, 10ths), 1, 0)
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| [0,1,1,0] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoTi3KTC1WsFVIqcxLzM1M1og20VEwNABhIGEaq2nNy5UDVGdoUJIBUlaUWpCaWKIBUpFYVJRYGZ%20TmpdekqEBMUcTpLygKDOvBCqbmZYGlYpPLwJqTC2KTy0sTcwphorqQAzWBNI6CgaaANTXtP2SAAAA)

Answer (score 0):

More generic approach :-)

```
print series = dynamic([4, 10, 100, 5])
| mv-apply series to typeof(int) on (summarize make_list(iff(series >= 10, 1, 0)))
```

| list_ |
| --- |
| [0,1,1,0] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAysoyswrUShOLcpMLVawVUipzEvMzUzWiDbRUTA0AGEgYRqryctVo5BbpptYUJBTCVNdkq9QUlmQmp%20mATRCUyE/T0GjuDQ3N7EosypVITcxOzU%20J7O4RCMzLU0DqsPOFmKojoKBpqYmAMyAdNd7AAAA)

Comment: Thanks David! Is it more efficient than using -mv-expand on the series and then aggregated it back into series ?

Comment: If you want to apply an operation on multiple rows and each time stay in the context of a single row, mv-apply is what you need (think on a scenario where you have a table with multiple rows and each row holds a series)